# TypeScript object type with generic result syntax error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I get syntax error when when trying to assign value as the result of generic `Merge` into object type(type of key-value):

```js
type Merge<a,b> = any

type test<P, S= any, K= any> = {
    jsx1?: (state: Merge<K, S>, props: P, nextJsx?) => JSX.Element; //ok
    jsx2?: ({state: S, props: P, nextJsx}) => JSX.Element; // ok
    jsx3?: ({ state: Merge<K, S>, props: P, nextJsx }) => JSX.Element; // error - why?
    //                    ^ WebStorm: ", expected"     ^ VSCode: ';' expected.(1005)
};
```

Why is that considered syntax error? How can I assign `jsx3->state` to type `Merge`?

TypeScript 4.4.4.

TS Playground:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAeAhgGgEYD4oF4o0A7EAKDNEimAgGdgUAFDKAZUJJFYGlPS8hAN5koYqACs6ADwCMAfgBcUABQM0tZXCSoerNjlZh4AezB1lLKMQjTgAKRnyAlATz22ADQB0AUQA2EAC2EMTAANxQAPRRJgDWouJS0gBMSqpC6prsRqbmlqw2do7SAL6u+O5efoEhYZExUPGJYskAzOkqQlBZEFoIyCh67IZQxmYWUFZFDjJQ5W5QHj4BwaER0VFQCKbwUAC0UADuABYg8i2b4tc3t2IAescQWAwm8EHKAESstpAAxrQACafG6PABudD+JkBfSgAHJwnDttJ-kDvCpZAAGTEAVmcZFK4TIQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the signature `({state: S, props: P, nextJsx}) => JSX.Element`, `S` and `P` are not types, they are identifiers. In this context, the colon `:` does not mean a type annotation, it means rebinding the name of a property, like in the following example:

```
const obj = {foo: 23};

// bar is not a type annotation here
const {foo: bar} = obj;

// 23
console.log(bar);
```

I'm not sure what the usefulness of parameter rebinding would be in a type declaration, but for better or worse, that's what it means. So the error is because `Merge<K, S>` is not a valid identifier for rebinding; but in fact both your `jsx2` and your `jsx3` declarations have problems, it's just that you didn't get an error for the other one.

The solution is to put the types in a place where, contextually, they actually are types; i.e. in the parameter's type annotation.

```
type Test<P, S=any, K=any> = {
    jsx1?: (state: Merge<K, S>, props: P, nextJsx?) => JSX.Element;
    jsx2?: (params: {state: S, props: P, nextJsx}) => JSX.Element;
    jsx3?: (params: {state: Merge<K, S>, props: P, nextJsx}) => JSX.Element;
}
```

Note the parameter is a single object named `params`, and its type now occurs in a type annotation context so it is not parsed as rebinding identifiers. Also, although there is a single named parameter `params` in the type declaration, it is still perfectly possible to do parameter destructuring (and rebinding, if you want to) when you actually implement these functions:

```
const test: Test<number, number, number> = {
    jsx2: ({state, props, nextJsx}) => console.log(state, props, nextJsx),
    jsx3: ({state, props, nextJsx}) => console.log(state, props, nextJsx),
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&jsx=4#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAeAggGigIQHxQF4oBXAOwGtSB7Ad1IFgAoJ0SKAFQgGdgUAFLAGUCAQ1IgsAaVHj8RAN5MoyqACsuADwCMAfgBcUABQ8RwCAbhJUkobixh4VMFwMCopCBuAApTToCUhPhklLSkANxKKuoaAEz6RmAi8CIAti5Q8iZmBoL2js6uWB5evhoAvoEEwRTUdJGMKmqaAMwJhkkp6QZZwKbmsAjIKDZQgnZQDk4ZbiU+mpVBJLVhDeVMTADGVKQ8UGY8Bpw8KKTEqQBGCMXnV-A3lwhymVHKMbEGhr39+dPFnvMKlV8NtdlQADYQAB04KoiGMfTMv2c-1Kmn8GFezQ0LU+3yRkwKXFRgMW1SgoK4EOhsPh2QgyOJ7gBZQxTHKDSAA)

Comment: you are correct - `jsx2` and `jsx3` was a mistake and not what I intended. I intended to assign to the first argument the type, as you showed. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are destructuring your objects with different names in `jsx2` and `jsx3`, instead of typing them. And in case of `jsx3` this is invalid syntax. What you want to do, is to properly type function argument:

```js
type Merge<A,B> = any;

type JSX2Args<P, S> = {
    state: S,
    props: P,
    nextJsx: unknown
}

type JSX3Args<P, S, K> = {
    state: Merge<K, S>,
    props: P,
    nextJsx: unknown
}

type test<P, S= any, K= any> = {
    jsx1?: (state: Merge<K, S>, props: P, nextJsx?) => JSX.Element;
    jsx2?: (arg: JSX2Args<P, S>) => JSX.Element; 
    jsx3?: ({ state, props, nextJsx }: JSX3Args<P, S, K>) => JSX.Element;
};
```